# How to connect Adapter with Presenter in MVP?

Tags: android, adapter, mvp

In RecyclerView I have a `ViewHolder` with VideoView and `Button` "Like" with the state (selected or not).

My Presenter have a method which will update "Like" status in the model - VideoEntity.
In callback I need to update View form Presenter, so I call `getView().updateItem(VideoEntity entity)`.
After that, I should find recyclerView entity position, and invalidate item.
So I want to avoid that.

In classic architecture, i can call some method from `ViewHolder`, get some callback there and update changed data.

How to migrate this pseudo-code to MVP pattern?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContainerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...
    rx.subscribe(result -> holder.update(result));
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(ContainerViewHolder holder) {
    if (haveBackgroundRequests) { rx.unsubscribe(holder); }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One presenter for one viewHolder.
I found solution here: https://github.com/remind101/android-arch-sample

Comment: for those who can't wait https://github.com/remind101/android-arch-sample/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/remind101/archexample

Comment: Where are you making the network request for your vieholder data with the linked github profile?